# How to delete all cells that do not contain specific values (in VBA/Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I fully didn't understand how to follow the answer in [vba deleting rows that do not contain set values defined in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019304/vba-deleting-rows-that-do-not-contain-set-values-defined-in-range) (I need to use VBA for this). From what I gathered, i need to specify an array, then use some if then stuff.

In my case, I want to create something that will search just a specified column and delete all values that do not contain specific letters/numbers. 1,2,3,4,5,s,f,p,a,b,c,o are the numbers/letters i want to keep. Cells which do not contain these values (even 11 or 1s should be deleted), I want only to delete the cell (not the whole row) and shift the cells below it up (i believe you can do this with the default .delete command).

For example my columns look like this:

p
a
1
2
5
s
f
s
8

31
4
f

I want to screen my data so that all blank cells and all cells which do not contain the numbers or letter mentioned above (e.g. 31 and 8 in this case) are automatically deleted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: come on its very simple. reverse engineer the array. stick all the values you want to delete into the array and then apply that as a filter - so if a cell equals a value from the array then delete it

Comment: Your question as stated above is different from your original one. Can you provide some sample data?  Do the values you want to keep exist by themseleves in cells, or are they part of other text?

Comment: @mehow I am very much a VBA noob. I understand the basics, not very good at much else, and i tried reverse engineering some other code I found but it didn't work.

Comment: And @mehow, i want to delete cells which ARE NOT part of the array- sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @user3084100 exactly, which means you need an alternate array containing all the strings you want to delete! reverse engineer the original idea

Comment: .Replace unwanted values with blanks and then sort the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
Sub Main()

Dim dontDelete
dontDelete = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "s", "f", "p", "a", "b", "c", "o")

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim isThere As Boolean

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    For j = LBound(dontDelete) To UBound(dontDelete)
        If StrComp(Range("A" & i), dontDelete(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isThere = True
        End If
    Next j
    If Not isThere Then
        Range("A" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
    isThere = False
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I used this in the end! Worked with a simple copy n' paste, don't have a clue how it works though...

Comment: @user3084100 glad to hear it worked in the end. Consider accepting the answer that helped you:)

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range

    'C1:C5 has values to keep
    sKeep = Chr(0) & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("C1:C5").Value), _
                                Chr(0)) & Chr(0)

    Set rngSearch = Range("A1:A100")

    For x = rngSearch.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = rngSearch.Cells(x)
        If InStr(sKeep, Chr(0) & c.Value & Chr(0)) = 0 Then
            c.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteValues()
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Arr(1 To 3) As String

Arr(1) = "1"
Arr(2) = "2"
Arr(3) = "3"

Range("A1").Select

For x = 1 To 10
    For i = 1 To 3
        If ActiveCell.Value = Arr(i) Then
            ActiveCell.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x

End Sub
```

This will loop through range("a1:a10") and delete any cell where the value = any of the array values (1,2,3)

You should hopefully be able to work with this code and suit it to your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Another way :) Which doesn't delete the cells in a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDEL As Range
    Dim strDel As String
    Dim arrDel
    Dim i As Long

    strDel = "1,11,Blah" '<~~ etc... You can pick this from a range as well
    arrDel = Split(strDel, ",")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Columns(1) '<~~ Change this to the relevant column
        For i = LBound(arrDel) To UBound(arrDel)
            .Replace What:=arrDel(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngDEL = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rngDEL Is Nothing Then rngDEL.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End With
End Sub
```